# Wrong tax class

Tags: taxes, germany

A few weeks ago I moved from Brazil to Germany to work for a IT company. I went to the Bürgerbüro to register my residence. The  employee who did my paperwork asked if I was married. I am married to a Brazilian woman who will be staying there at least until the first semester of 2020. Meanwhile, she will visit me every few months. I said exactly this to the Bürgerbüro employee.

What's weird is that my Steuerklasse is 3, which I believe should be only given to people whose SO already lives in Germany (not my case). Is this right? Should I take any action to correct this, in case it is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm not a tax attorney)
When I was last in Germany I had Steuerklasse 1 even though I was married to a US citizen (who never moved to Germany).
I assume that you just had a misunderstanding with the person recording your residence. Or it's also possible that the information wasn't given to other agencies in the same way (Finanzamt is what handles the tax status).

You should call up the Finanzamt and ask what you should do. If you had any income this year you should prepare to pay additional taxes after you file your tax return.